# Buffers do no behave properly

Tags: string, assembly, char, output, x86-16

I am miserable at assembly programming and ask for your help. What I do not understand is why do I lose the characters of a string from my buffer even though there is plenty of room in it?

My readBuffer size is 32 and writeBuffer size is 64, what my program does is add a space after a period and makes the first letter capital.

EXAMPLE:

```
Good.morning.people hehehe in the jungle the mighty jungle  //this is the data
Good. Morning. People hehehe in the jungle the mighty jungle //this is the output
```

WHAT MY PROGRAM DOES:

```
Good.morning.people hehehe in the jungle the mighty jungle  //this is the data
Good. Morning. People hehehe in e jungle the mighty jungle //this is the output
```

As you can see I end up with 'e' instead of 'the'

Here is the my code which does the editing:

```
Read:

    MOV bx, DataHandle          
    CALL ReadBuffer         
    CMP ax, 0               ;ax = how many symbols did I read
    JE  closeWrite          ;if 0 then close write file

;Editing the string

    MOV  cx, ax               ;CX FOR LOOPING
    MOV  si, offset rBuff     ;read buffer = si
    MOV di, offset wBuff      ;write buffer = di

  Do_It:

    MOV dl, [si]
    CMP dl, '.'                 ;comparing to period
    JNE Keep_Going              ;if not period put it in di (write buffer)
    MOV dh, [si+1]              ;put the char after the period in dh
    CMP dh, ' '                 ;check if space is after it
    JNE If_capital              ;if not I check if it is a capital letter
    MOV dh, [si+2]              ;if there was a space I add the char after the space
    CMP dh, 'a'                 ;checking if it is a capital letter
    JB  Keep_Going  
    CMP dh, 'z'     
    JA  Keep_Going  
    SUB byte ptr [si+2], 32     ;turn it into a  capital letter

  Keep_Going:

    MOV [di], dl                ;put the  char into writebuff
    INC si
    INC di
    LOOP Do_It
    JMP Finishin

  If_capital:

    CMP dh, 'a'     
    JB  Add_Space       
    CMP dh, 'z'     
    JA  Add_Space   
    SUB byte ptr [si+1], 32

  Add_Space:

    MOV [di], '.'       
    INC di
    MOV [di], ' '
    INC di
    INC si
    JMP Do_It

;Write the result

  Finishin:
    MOV cx, ax          
    CALL checkOnScreen       ;print it to command line
    MOV bx, WriteHandle         
    CALL    writeBuffer      ;print it
    CMP ax, rBuffSize        ;compare the size to 32
    JE  Read                 ;if it was 32 then read again
```

Comment: Could it be just your output function messing up? As far as I can see you are passing the original length to it.

Comment: **Step** through your code, line by line, in the **debugger**

Answer (score 1):

You write only 32 bytes of `wBuff`. This is after the first run: "Good. Morning. People hehehe in ". Since the line is longer, the rest is behind the boarder of 32 byte. Then you reset the pointers to `rBuff` and `wBuff` and read the next block: "e jungle the mighty jungle". That block is attached to the written line.

Consider that the block to be written has a variable length. You can calculate the length by subtracting the offset of `wBuff` from `DI` (`sub di, OFFSET wBuff`) after changing the `JMP Do_It` to `LOOP Do_It`.

I can't show a working example since I can't interpret relevant parts of your code (`CMP ax, rBuffSize`, `JE  Read` ???).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for input guys, I managed to do it myself this time. The problem was

```
Finishin:
    MOV cx, ax          
    CALL checkOnScreen       
    MOV bx, WriteHandle         
    CALL    writeBuffer      
    CMP ax, rBuffSize        
    JE  Read
```

New code:

```
    Finishin:
        MOV cx, strLength2         ;length of writebuffer
        CALL checkOnScreen       
        MOV bx, WriteHandle         
        CALL    writeBuffer      
        CMP ax, rBuffSize        ;ax was messed up so I changed it to strLength1 or readBuffer
        JE  Read
```